# CRC Algorithms Basics

Tags: microcontroller, crc

I am reading about CRC algorithms. And have a few basic doubts

[Referred Link](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00068118-using-the-crc-peripheral-in-the-stm32-family-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

I have 3 questions :

1. Suppose, I have a Microcontroller and an EEPROM. I have read that CRC employs different algorithms. So, my question, how to check if the data sent by the Microcontroller with Checksum will be decoded by the EEPROM correctly, if the Microcontroller employs a different protocol and the EEPROM employs a different protocol to code and decode a checksum? Is the checksum coding and decoding algorithm the same or how to check?
2. Is checksum done for all data transactions or only specific data transactions? Is it a mandatory thing to do for each data transfer?
3. Last question, Is checksum only done for data values or address values too?

Comment: EEPROMs don't decode a CRC checksum - they will store it and the MCU can check to see that the EEPROM data integrity is correct by recalculating the CRC from the EEPROM data and comparing it with the original stored value. No mention (CTRL-F) of EEPROMs in the linked document.

Comment: Thank you. For a different IC which can decode the checksum, how is my question 1 tackled?

Comment: If you have a specific EEPROM, state which it is, to know what CRC it uses natively. Not many EEPROMS use hardware CRC so you are free to use whatever CRC or any other hashing algorithm you want.

Comment: No. I donot have a specific EEPROM. I just wanted to state one example with some IC to understand the concepts and doubts I had

Comment: @Justme , From your comment, are you saying there are two types of CRC - Native CRC in the Chip and the Hardware CRC ?

Comment: If you could share any document or any material which could clarify my doubts regarding this, it would be helpful for me

Comment: @Newbie No there are no two types of CRC. Either something supports some CRC natively in hardware or it doesn't. If you want material go read Wikipedia article on CRC. If you don't have an EEPROM that supports CRC then you can use anything you want. Even SD cards support CRC in command and data packets but you don't have to use them.

Comment: Ok. Sure. But my basic doubt - If I send a data with a CRC Checksum using an algorithm, does the receiver device, will use the same algorithm to compute the checksum for the data or it does not compute the checksum? I just want to understand whether the Microcontroller can do CRC or the receiver device can do CRC? If the receive can do CRC, how will it do? With same algorithm or different algorithm

Comment: @Newbie the receiving device may not support CRC at all. In which case you are free to use any algorithm to verify the integrity of data, by including your checksum/CRC in the data. If it supports CRC, then you must use the same CRC or it won't accept the data. Both devices must use the same algorithm. But since you don't say which devices we can't tell which devices support CRC and which don't, and if they do, what algorithm they support.

Comment: If the receiving device does not support CRC, does the MCU again take back the data to check for CRC or how? And I am asking in general, - Is CRC Applicable for data or for address too?

Comment: If you store some data and its CRC into memory, you can read data and CRC back and see if the CRC matches the data. You can include address of stored data into the CRC if you want to. If it is a message to another MCU then it may not have an address. In general, you can do anything you want, for any data you can calculate the CRC in any way you want to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the same algorithm on your MCU. That also includes initial constants and data size - if the algorithm works on UINT8, don't use INT32.
2. That depends on the specific device, you didn't specify which one is it, so we can't know.
3. See #2.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on point 1, please/

Comment: If the EEPROM uses CRC-16 with seed of 0x1234, you should use CRC-16 with seed 0x1234.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this subject only depending on Application notes. I do not understand what you mean by 0x1234

Comment: 0x1234 is a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Ok. What does seed 0x1234 mean? Could you please provide an answer for the 3 questions to clear my doubts, please

Comment: @Newbie Seed means to which value the CRC is initialized before calculations. And you already have answers to your three questions, your questions are just so general that they can't be answered more precisely unless you have a precise question. Explaining how CRCs work could fill a book. Please do some own research as well.